# Configure Squid to permanently cache specific directories?

Tags: squid, cache

Can Squid be configured to permanently cache specific directories of a web site?
In the diagram below, the lan1 [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) should cache `www.example.com/x` and 
`www.example.com/y` directories permanently. Contents of directories `/x /y` and `/z`
are write once.

```
              xww.example.com
                /w /x /y /z
                  Apache
         ------------------------
         Slow Internet Connection
         ------------------------
          lan1  |  lan2  |  lan3
                |        |
          cache |  cache |  cache
          /x /y |  /x /z |  /y /z
          Squid |  Squid |  Squid
         ------ | ------ | ------
         Browser| Browser|Browser
         Browser| Browser|Browser
         Browser| Browser|Browser
         Browser| Browser|Browser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `cache` and `refresh_pattern` will define how your SQUID cache performs.  You can use `cache` to specify the directory and `refresh_pattern` to define how it expires.

You can use `override-expire` to enforce a minimum age, which violates the HTTP standard.  I do not believe there is a setting for true permanence.

[Cache Tuning Parameters](http://www.visolve.com/squid/squid30/tuning.php)

Comment: For future reference, http://serverfault.com/questions/118541/squid-utility-command-to-force-a-cache-load-from-a-local-hard-drive is related to this as well.