# Squid utility command to force a cache load from a local hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, squid, cache

Is there a [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) utility command to force a cache load from a local hard drive?

```
              xww.example.com
                /w /x /y /z
                  Apache
         ------------------------
         Slow Internet Connection
         ------------------------
          lan1  |  lan2  |  lan3
                |        |
          cache |  cache |  cache
          /x /y |  /x /z |  /y /z
          Squid |  Squid |  Squid
         ------ | ------ | ------
         Browser| Browser|Browser
         Browser| Browser|Browser
         Browser| Browser|Browser
         Browser| Browser|Browser
```

For example, plug the USB hard drive into the machine on lan1 that is running Squid. Then invoke a command like:

```
$ suqid-util\
 --force-cache-load\
 --url-root http://www.example.com/x\
 --local-root /mnt/usb1\
 --recursive
```

This would be useful when a 2TB hard drive can be hand carried to a location with slow Internet connection.

OR

A better solution using something other than [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)? I am still hunting.

Comment: What a perverse idea.  Much more fun than a station wagon full of tapes.  I love it.

Comment: What's the content?  Is it audio and video files?  HTML files with embedded MPEG?  Content dictates options.

Comment: You could populate a squid cache (in a VM, say, or something easily hand-carried) with wget on a fast link, and move that to slow link side, set it up as a parent, wget the resident squid cache on the slow link, lather, rinse, repeat.  Ugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with this but it seems others have used `wget` to spider the content via the proxy, thus populating the cache.

I can't think of any reason why you wouldn't be able to copy the `cache_dir` to your hard drive.

Out of curiosity, what exactly are you trying to do?

[Using wget to populate SQUID cache](http://www.vias.org/wirelessnetw/wndw_05_09_02_08.html)

Comment: Mirror subsets of an increasing collection of static audio-video content to remote locations with slow Internet connections where the opportunistic delivery of microSD cards on the backs of pigeons can used to improve through-put. Well, actually people with hard drives may substitute for the pigeons under management control.

Comment: It seems like there should be a better solution than SQUID for something like this.

I hear there's heavy latency with pigeons but with modern storage densities the throughput isn't too bad.

Comment: wget link should be placed in the answers to: http://serverfault.com/questions/118518/configure-squid-to-permanently-cache-specific-directories

Comment: I appreciate you accepting.  Did this work for you?